# Least hardware intensive cgi script web service

Tags: database, performance, cgi, web

I'm beginning to write a webservice that won't have a great interface nor will be complicated but could have lots of small requests, with small responses of data.

So I wan't to start making it relatively good for a good amount of accesses and was thinking what's the best option.

My current layout is:
mysql with perl running on apache(linux obviously)

What is best combination?(not necessarily from the option below)

- DB: sqlite < postgre/mysql
- CGI: java < ruby,python,perl,php < C/C++
- WEB: nginx, apache2, lighttpd

I would prefer not to use compiled cgi for now, perhaps later...

Of course, please also take in mind the documentation available and work required to get an alternate combination running and developing for it.

Comment: If it won't have a great interface, you might as well make it a really crappy interface, make a C++ application that interfaces directly with your db, and answers a super simple query on a specific port. No web server required, compiled, minimal overhead.

Answer (score 1):

For quick, easy, and scalable, try node.js ( http://nodejs.org ).

From the node.js home page:

Node's goal is to provide an easy way to build scalable network programs. In the "hello world" web server example above (below), many client connections can be handled concurrently.

node.js 'hello world' example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

For database persistence, you can connect it to sqlite ( http://code.google.com/p/node-sqlite ) for a simple embedded database, or you can use mysql ( https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native ).

From the sqlite home page:

SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

You already know about MySQL.

Comment: Running a http server is not my idea of least hardware intensive. Also, sqlite is far from being a efficient db solution...